# Routing annotation is not working for 18nRoutingBundle

Tags: php, symfony, routes, internationalization

[I18nRoutingBundle](https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleI18nRoutingBundle) doesn't seem to be working for Symfony 3.4.

**JobController.php**

```
use BeSimple\I18nRoutingBundle\Routing\Annotation\I18nRoute;

class JobController extends Controller
{
    /**
     *
     * @I18nRoute({ "en": "/jobs", "pl": "/ogloszenia" }, name="jobs")
     * @Method("GET")
     */
    public function jobsListAction()
    {
        $jobs = $this->getDoctrine()
            ->getRepository(Job::class)
            ->findAllActive();

        return $this->render('job/list.html.twig', [
            'jobs' => $jobs,
        ]);
    }
}
```

**config.yml**

```
be_simple_i18n_routing:
    annotations: true
```

**error:**

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("I18nRoute "jobs" (pl) does not exist.").
```

I was struggling to find any other bundle for annotation routing i18n. Any help?

Comment: the error happen when you try to generate a route (path) for the specified controller in a twig view files? can you show the code?

Comment: @Matteo yes this cause the problem: `{{ path('jobs') }}`

Comment: very strange, seems supported by the doc. I usually use [this bundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle) but you could try to open an issue on the repo in order to ask directly to the author

Comment: Thanks @Matteo. Can you use annotation routing in JMSI18nRoutingBundle? I couldn't find it in doc.